# Which countries and regions speak Portuguese?

Tags: localização

**[en]**

Which countries and regions speak Portuguese nowadays? And these countries/regions which use it as official language?

I have a notion of which countries use the language, but do not know what use it officially.

**[pt]**

Quais países e regiões falam Português nos dias de hoje? E destes países/regiões quais usam como língua oficial?

Eu tenho uma noção de quais países usam o idioma, mas não sei quais o usam oficialmente.

Comment: Eu acho uma pergunta apropriada e interessante.

Comment: Só uma coisa, quanto ao teu texto "Se a pergunta estiver fora do escopo pode fechar.", isso seria mais apropriado para um comentário e não para o corpo da pergunta em si.

Comment: -1: não mostra tentativa de pesquisa.

Comment: @ANeves está pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/60/8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Língua Oficial (*Official Language*)

Que eu saiba, são esses que reconhecem o Português como língua oficial.
*As far as I know, the following recognize Portuguese as their official language*.

- Brasil (Brazil)
- Portugal (Portugal)
- São Tomé e Príncipe (São Tomé and Príncipe)
- Angola (Angola)
- Moçambique (Mozambique)
- Cabo Verde (Cape Verde)
- Timor Leste (East Timor)
- Guiné-Bissau (Guinea-Bissau)
- Guiné Equatorial (Equatorial Guinea)
- Macau (Macau)<sup>†</sup>

<sub>† Macau não é um país, mas uma cidade autónoma da China. Porém, reconhece Português como língua oficial.

*Macau is not a country, but an autonomous city in China. However, it does recognize Portuguese as an official language.*</sub>

## Outros

Outras regiões/países falam Português, mas não reconhecem como língua oficial.
*Other regions/countries speak Portuguese, but don't recognize it as an official language.*

- O estado de Goa, na Índia
  *The state of Goa, in India*

Comment: Por curiosidade, Macau fica na China, para quem não sabe!

Comment: Sim, é uma *região administrativa especial* da China, semalhante ao Hong Kong.

Comment: [Goa, na Índia.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa)

Comment: @VictorStafusa é verdade que o estado da Goa fala português, mas não é "oficialmente" reconhecido. Não sei se o autor da pergunta queria alguma distinção.

Comment: Macau não é um país.

Comment: Para se adequar melhor a resposta eu editei a questão, a resposta é bem completa, só gostaria que discriminasse as regiões que usam oficialmente, por enquanto +1

Comment: @ANeves "Quais países e regiões falam Português?"

Comment: Editei a resposta - inclui a diferença entre linga oficial e outros. Também marquei/grifei o Macau, realmente não sendo um país. Acho que continua satisfazendo a pergunta, porém está um pouco mais categorizado/organizado

Comment: Obrigado @VictorStafusa pela ajuda no português (e inglês!) :P